# Manipulation of HTTPS method in telnet

Tags: http, telnet

I have a problem properly creating a GET request and send in telnet. Generally I want to send something like this:

```
telent www.example.com 443(Press enter)
```

Then:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1 (here i try to go to new line)
Host:www.example.com
```

But I do not know how to change new line. When I press enter after the GET line the connection is closed. How can I go to the new line from Linux command-line?

Comment: Are you sure you're actually connecting to a web server? The command line you've specified will take you to port 23, the telnet port, by default.  Try `telnet www.example.com 80<enter>` instead.

Comment: Also, when doing basic testing, try a 1.0 request first which won't require multiple headers - just `GET / HTTP/1.0<enter><enter>` is a valid request, because 1.0 doesn't require a Host header.

Comment: You cannot talk plain text to a SSL connection (port 443 is usually HTTPS). Use `openssl s_client` for this.

Comment: OK, you are right. When I change port on 80 it's works. So to use GET command with ssl i chould use openssl c_cilent?

Comment: I asked about it beacuse my scanner return sth like this (checking appache chunked vulnerability): **telnet <site> 443POST /x.html HTTP/1.1Host: <site>Transfer-Encoding: chunkedc00000000**

Comment: I don't think this is a good question for Security. Superuser will be the place for it.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Are you executing some exploit against some server? What scanner are you using? Give details please.

Comment: "...So to use GET command with ssl i chould use openssl c_cilent?..." - Yes, that's what I said and what you should do.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you're trying to connect to port 443.

This won't work with `telnet` as you need to set up TLS (443 is HTTPS, not HTTP), which you can't do with `telnet`.

For testing, while it won't be interactive like `telnet`, [you can use `openssl` or `gnutls`](https://www.bearfruit.org/2008/04/17/telnet-for-testing-ssl-https-websites/).